# In GraphQL .NET, how do I specify that a query can take optional parameters?

Tags: graphql, graphql-dotnet

Let's say I want to be able to query for a user by specifying their ID, *or* by specifying some other identifier, like email address.

How do you construct the root Query object to accept that?

Given this

```
public class MyQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public MyQuery(IUserService userService)
    {
        Name = "Query";

        Field<UserType>(
            "user",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<IntGraphType>() { Name = "id" },
                new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>() { Name = "email" }
            ),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                int? id = context.GetArgument<int>("id");
                if (id != null)
                {
                    return userService.GetUserById(id);
                }
                string email = context.GetArgument<string>("email");
                if (email != null)
                {
                    return userService.GetUserByEmail(email);
                }
                return null;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Is that the right way to do it?  Will `context.GetArgument()` return `null` if it doesn't find the argument in the query? Or does providing two arguments to the `QueryArguments` mean that both arguments are required for the query?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
arguments: new QueryArguments(
  new QueryArgument<IntGraphType>() { Name = "id" },
  new QueryArgument<StringGraphType>() { Name = "email" }
)
```

This means that these arguments are nullable, which would make them optional.

```
arguments: new QueryArguments(
  new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>>() { Name = "id" },
  new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>() { Name = "email" }
)
```

Wrapping the `GraphType` in `NonNullGraphType` specifies that the value should be non-null, making it required to provide a non-null value.

By default `GetArgument<TType>` will return `default(TType)` if the argument does not exist.  You could also use:

```
context.GetArgument<string>("email", defaultValue: "my default value");
```

Comment: So I could force `GetArgument<TType>` to return `null` if the argument does not exist by doing `context.GetArgument<string>("email", defaultValue: null)`?

Comment: Yes.  Providing a default value is optional (`defaultValue` is an optional parameter).  The default for a string would be null.